# Compare between two ways of defining CNN layers

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, image-processing

We know that the parameter tuning of the neural network is somehow like dealing with a blackbox; there is never a unified model for every problem. To this end, I've always wondered if the following `keras` layers:

```
layer = Conv2D(128, (2, 2))(layer)
layer = Conv2D(128, (2, 2))(layer)
```

are equivalent to:

```
layer = Conv2D(256, (2, 2))(layer)
```

in terms of prediction accuracy and which one is more likely to capture more features from input images based on your experience.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [Keras API documentation](https://keras.io/api/layers/convolution_layers/convolution2d/), without specifying an activation function, the default is a linear/identity activation.

Towards your question, it's easy to see why both of your layers, the 128-channel composite one and the 256-channel single layer, are not equivalent: the receptive field of the composite one is actually 3x3. That happens because, when you perform two 2x2 convolutions, on the second operation the each input pixel actually contains information from the immediate neighborhood in the original image.

Regarding which one is able to capture more information, it can't be so easily assessed. However, the single layer should have less parameters for most choices of $\text{nchannels}$ ($2\times2\times256\times \text{nchannels}$ versus $2\times2\times128\times \text{nchannels}+2\times2\times128\times 128$) and also a smaller receptive field, so the composite layer should be more expressive.